# How do I replace the HUD functions from Rhythmbox with Clementine?

Tags: rhythmbox, hud, clementine

I've been searching for this for a while and I can't find anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

In Edit > plugins there is 'Notification popups' plugin. You can anytime deactivate the plugin, but I'm not sure if there is Clementine plugin for Rhythmbox.